# Android listview overlaps edit text field

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im having some layout issues, what I want to happen
1. My **discussions_edit_text_wrap** should be at the bottom of the view, when keyboard slides up it must be visible above the keyboard

2. The **discussions_list_view** should be just above the **discussions_edit_text_wrap**, also when keyboard slides up this should scroll to enable the user to view content. When the keyboard is closed this listview should not occupy the whole screen even if it has alot of items.

---

What happens
1. As the code is currently the list view shows but occupies the whole screen and runs underneath the edit text which sits at the top of the screen.

Help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

---

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/create_discussions_layout"
            android:background="?attr/drawer_background"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:padding="10dp">

        <!-- list of discussions -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/discussions_list_wrap"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/discussions_list_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:divider="@color/divider_light"
                    android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/discussions_empty"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?text_small"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/no_notes_available"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

            <View
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="?divider_light"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- edittext areas for discussions content -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/discussions_edit_text_wrap"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="8"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="left">

                <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/discussions_edit"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="?attr/text_color_light"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:hint="@string/add_new_comment"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:minWidth="200dp">

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/discussions_comment_button"
                        style="?main_button"
                        android:text="@string/comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

### Update

After adding **android:layout_above="@+id/discussions_edit_text_wrap"** and **android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `android:layout_below="@id/discussions_list_wrap"` inside LinearLayout --> discussions_edit_text_wrap  or even `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for LinearLayout --> discussions_edit_text_wrap

Comment: Could you possibly use weightSum seeing as you have a linear layout?

Comment: ok I have added android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" to android:id="@+id/discussions_edit_text_wrap" AND android:layout_above="@+id/discussions_edit_text_wrap" on android:id="@+id/discussions_list_wrap" its starting to loook like something but now the relative layout fills the whole screen

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your updated screen for clarity..

Comment: that is almost what I want except that listview must not be covering the whole screen, it should be 40 or 50% of screen size

Comment: maby i should use weight sum?

Comment: @Francois you should try adding **@username** wen refering for any changes or an clarification requested by them, cause it sends a notification of your updates which is very important.. As of your question, plz do try adding weightsum..